# Where to find images for OpenCV tutorials?

Tags: opencv

I have been following tutorials from the official [OpenCV documentations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html)

However, I am hoping to find the images they used in the tutorials so that I can reproduce results. Is there a repository of those images somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the source of [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip).

"opencv\sources\samples\data" contains most of these sample images in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try [opencv-extra](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra), at least some of the tutorials use images from there.

For example:

[image: Lena]